# Очень странное поведение Laravel

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel

Доброй ночи. Имею два отдельных проекта `api` и веб-интерфейс на `Laravel`.
Метод веб-интерфейса запроса к api:

```
public function getCurlApi($url, $postData){
        $request = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl.$url);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($request);
        return $response;
    }
```

Middleware `api`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'text' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'request' => $request->url()
        ]);
    }
```

Проблема в том что:

При выполнении запроса через мой метод в ответе приходит следующее:

```
"{"text":"mysite","request":"http:\/\/api.cafedra.com\/api\/account\/login"}"
```

А должно быть так:

```
"{"text":"api.mysite","request":"http:\/\/api.cafedra.com\/api\/account\/login"}"
```

Таким образом `api` совершенно непонятно откуда берёт настройки `DB` из веб-интерфейса, что является отдельным проектом. Прошу помощи, так как уже два часа сижу над этой проблемой.

Comment: А что у Вас лежит в .env под ключём "DB_DATABASE"?

Comment: @nikitar На проекте api лежит `api.mysite`, на втором проекте `mysite`. Обращение к `api` - это же совсем отдельный проект, значит и настройки свои, а он их не использует и магическим образом берёт настройки веб-интерфейса. Таким образом при работе с БД выдает ошибку(

Comment: Я правильно понял, мидлвэйр api лежит в проекте с api? Или в проекте с веб-интерфейсом?

Comment: @nikitar Конечно же в `api`. Я создал тестовый роут для `get-запроса`. Так вот через браузерную строку по даному пути выводит правильные настройки.

Comment: У Вас явно что-то куда-то не туда смотрит, поведение действительно странное. Проекты расположены в разных директориях и абсолютно независимы друг от друга? Доступ к ним по разным доменам\ип?

Comment: @nikitar Вы совершенно правы, всё по разным директориям. Использую `OpenServer` + все домены настроены. Запрос доходит к `api` - иначе не было бы ответа `curl`.

Comment: Попытался воспроизвести те же условия локально - полёт нормальный. Будьте добры, отпишите, когда разберётесь, интересно, в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: @nikitar Я только то пытался обратиться к `api` через простой скрипт `php` - всё успешно. Установил заново `Laravel` - та же проблема.

Comment: Играться с хрустальным шаром - то ещё счастье. Сложно что-нибудь подсказать, не посмотрев в код.